# calculation of $E[\Phi(X)]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let, $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and let $\Phi(\cdot):\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be the CDF of a *standard normal* distribution. 
Then, what is the pdf of $Y=\Phi(X)$. Also, find $E[\Phi(X)]$.

**Note:-** 
Here, $Y=\Phi(X)\ne P(Z\le X)= \text{ some constant }$. Rather, in this case, $Y=\Phi(X)$ is a *non-degenerate* random variable.
And, so $E[\Phi(X)]\ne E[P(Z\le X)]=P(Z\le X)=\Phi\left(\dfrac{-\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right)$

**My attempt:-**

$$E[Y]=E[\Phi(X)]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi(x)f_X(x)dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\left( \int^{x}_{-\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( \frac{-1}{2}t^2 \right)dt \right) \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( \frac{-1}{2}{\bigg[\dfrac{x-u}{\sigma}}\bigg]^2 \right)dx \\\ =\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sigma}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{x}_{-\infty}\exp\left[\dfrac{-1}{2}\Bigg(t^2+\Big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)^2\Bigg)\right]dt dx $$

This is where i am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is true that $$\mathbf{E}[\Phi(X)]=\mathbf{P}(Z\leq X)$$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable independent of $X$. This is because we can write $\Phi(X)=\mathbf{P}(Z\leq X\mid X)$.

Comment: $$\underset{X}{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}}\,\left[ \Pr \left[ Z<X\left| X \right. \right] \right]=\underset{X}{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}}\,\left[ \underset{Z}{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}}\,\left[ {{I}_{\left\{ Z<X \right\}}}\left| Z \right. \right] \right]=\mathbb{E}\left[ {{I}_{\left\{ Z<X \right\}}} \right]=\Pr \left[ Z<X \right].$$   Taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4140516/415432 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1125935/415432

Answer (score 3):

The CDF of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb P(X\le x)=\mathbb P\Bigg(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)=\Phi\Big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\Big).
$$
Therefore
$$
U:=\Phi\Big(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)
$$
is uniform on $[0,1]$. From $Y=\Phi(X)$ we get
$$
Y=\Phi\Big(\sigma\,\Phi^{-1}(U)+\mu\Big)\,,\quad U=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(Y)-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)\,.
$$
The CDF of $Y$ is
$$
\mathbb P(Y\le y)=\mathbb P\Bigg(U\le\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)\Bigg)=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigg)\,.
$$
The expectation of $Y=\Phi(X)$ is
$$
\mathbb E[Y]=\int_0^1\Phi\Big(\sigma\,\Phi^{-1}(u)+\mu\Big)\,du\,.
$$